# Why can't I create a new schema with the owner set to dbo?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, permissions, schema, users

I created a test account for checking permissions against.
It currently has the db_datareader, db_datawriter, and db_ddladmin roles for the Northwind database.
But when it tries to create a new schema on Northwind, the creation fails if it tries to authorize dbo as the schema owner, what's up?

[image: Create Schema Failed]

```
Version: 
SQL Server Management Studio: 15.0.18183.0 
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools: 15.0.1487.0 
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC): 10.0.18362.1 
Microsoft MSXML: 3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer: 9.11.18362.0 Microsoft 
.NET Framework: 4.0.30319.42000 
Operating System: 10.0.18362
```

Comment: Can you disponibilish more informations about SQL Server Instance? Help>About>Copy Info

Comment: Sure:

SQL Server Management Studio: 15.0.18183.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools: 15.0.1487.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC): 10.0.18362.1
Microsoft MSXML: 3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer: 9.11.18362.0
Microsoft .NET Framework: 4.0.30319.42000
Operating System: 10.0.18362

Comment: The user is disabled in print screen image.  Try again after you enable user

Comment: I see that it has the X over it, but I don't think it's actually disabled, as my own account shows the same X over it under the Users node and I can still login and use that account (it's actually the one I'm using to administer permissions on this test account). Additionally, on another server the dbo user has the X on it too but there's a schema in the same database who's owner is dbo.

Comment: You tried with GUID in DBO? Try create schema with another user and Right click button DBO>Owned Schemas>"Select Schemas">OK. Showed same error?

Comment: If I create the schema with the test account first and leave the owner blank, then when I right click the DBO user and go to Owned Schemas and check off the new schema, I get the same error message as in my post: "Cannot find the principal 'dbo' because it does not exist or you do not have permission. For some reason my test account doesn't have permission to the dbo principal?

Comment: Also, I just figured out that the X on a user means you don't have access to the user (which is consistent with the error message I'm getting). Not sure why my new test account would not have access to the dbo user out of the gate.

Comment: Is the user a member of the db_owner role?

Comment: The test user is not part of the db_owner role.

Comment: These permissions will not give you the privileges to alter other user or create schema. To do this you need set your test user as a membership of db_accessadmin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The db_datareader, db_datawriter, and db_ddladmin permissions will not give the necessary privilege for this action.

> **db_datareader:**    Members of the db_datareader fixed database role can read all data from all user tables.
>
> **db_datawriter:**    Members of the db_datawriter fixed database role can add, delete, or change data in all user tables.
>
> **db_ddladmin:**  Members of the db_ddladmin fixed database role can run any Data Definition Language (DDL) command in a database.

As you can see, these permissions will give you privileges to create and manipulate some database structure. However, **they will not give you the privileges to alter other user or create schema**.

Check this image from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/media/permissions-of-database-roles.png?view=sql-server-ver15) of database level roles and permissions
[image]

Note that permission **db_ddladmin** does not grant you the privilege to create SCHEMA. To do this you need set your *test user* as a membership of **db_accessadmin**. This role will grant privileges to **create schema** and **alter any user**. The *alter any user* privileges will be necessary to set *dbo user* as a schema owner:

```
USE [your_database]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_accessadmin] ADD MEMBER [teste]
GO
```

After this, you will can authorize DBO in the new schema like:

```
USE [your_database]
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [test] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
```

Another role will grant permissions to do this is the db_owner, but is "some powerful" permission to this. That is why the correct role is db_accessadmin. You can read more about each permission at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15)

Remember to use the commands in the correct database with:

```
USE [your_database]
```